# Regular Expression for comments but not within a "string" / not in another container

Tags: regex, comments, match, regex-negation

So I need a regular expression for finding single line and multi line comments, but not in a string. (eg. `"my /* string"`)

for testing (`#` single line, `/*` & `*/` multi line):

```
# complete line should be found
lorem ipsum # from this to line end
/*
  all three lines should be found
*/ but not here anymore
var x = "this # should not be found"
var y = "this /* shouldn't */ match either"
var z = "but" & /* this must match */ "_"
```

SO does the syntax display really well; I basically want all the gray text.
I don't care if its a single regex or two separates. ;)

EDIT: one more thing. the opposite would also satisfy me, searching for a string which is not in a comment
this is my current string matching: `"[\s\S]*?(?<!\\)"` (indeed: will not work with `"\\"`)

EDIT2:
OK finally I wrote my own comment parser -.-
And if someone else is interested in the source code, grab it from here: https://github.com/relikd/CommentParser

Comment: What are you using it for? If you have a specific purpose in mind, someone may already have written something that does it for you.

Comment: The regex needed for that is ... non-trivial.  Which program(ming language) are you planning to use?  I have a C 'comment stripper' which can handle the C `/* ... */` comments; it is not designed to handle `#` comments (though it does handle C++ `//` comments OK).  And it has an inverse mode - print the comments and not the non-comment material.  But it is a non-negligible amount of C code that does that.

Comment: I'm writing a small syntax highlighter in ObjC but I thought there would be a generic regex rather than searching char by char :/

Comment: Excluding character strings is one major source of complexity that a regex does not handle easily. The full semantics of C comments are horrid. The slash and star that start the comment can be separated by an arbitrary number of backslash-newline character pairs, for example; ditto for the star-slash at the end of the comment. Technically, a C++ `//` comment can have an arbitrary number of backslash-newline pairs in between the two slashes. Any regex therefore has to be in a language where you are not reading 'one line at a time' for the C-style comments (the `#...EOL` comments are easier).

Comment: Also, consider the following. You probably want `#/*` to be a single line comment. And you probably don't want `#*/` to close an existing comment.

Comment: Of course, sane people don't write comments with the start symbol split across newlines - and maybe you're able to cater to just the sane and not the insane.  However, you need to be aware that in C, a backslash at the end of a line continues it onto the next - and that is almost the first transform that is made to the code (the only earlier ones deal with line endings and with trigraphs, so that `??/` is mapped to backslash before backslash-newline is removed).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok I think I have to use a parser… is your code somewhere available, or closed source?

Comment: @relikd: send me email - see my profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possibility (it does have an achilles heel that i'll get to):

```
(#[^"\n\r]*(?:"[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*)*[\r\n]|/\*([^*]|\*(?!/))*?\*/)(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

In action [here](http://regexr.com?2vv1t)

With the GLOBAL and DOTALL flags, but *not* the MULTILINE flag.

Explanation of the regex:

```
(
  #[^"\n\r]*                         Hash mark followed by non-" and non-end-of-line
    (?:"[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*)*        If any quotes in the comment, they must be balanced
    [\r\n]                           Followed by end-of-line ($ except we 
                                      don't have multiline flag)

  |                                  OR
  /\*([^*]|\*(?!/))*?\*/             /* xxx */ sort of comment
  )                                  BOTH FOLLOWED BY
(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)           only a *balanced* number of quotes for the 
                                      *rest of the code :O!*
```

However, this **relies** on balanced quotes being used throughout the text (it also doesn't take into account escaped quotes, but it's easy enough to modify the regex to take that into account).

If a user has a comment with a " in it that isn't balanced...boom. You're screwed!

Regex is generally not recommended by things like HTML/code parsing, but if you can rely on the fact that quotes have to balance when you define a string, etc, you can sometimes get away with it.

Since you are also parsing *comments*, which have *no set structure* (ie you are not guaranteed that quotes within comments will be balanced), you won't be able to find a regex solution that works here.

Anything you think up can be outwitted by an unbalanced quote in a comment somewhere (say the comment was `# remove all the " marks`), or by multiline strings (where on a given line there may be unbalanced quotes).

**Bottom line** - you can probably make a regex that will work in most cases, but not for all. To get something watertight you'll have to write some code.

Comment: +1 because it works better than all I tried for hours :D. Can you try the other way? maybe finding a string thats not in a comment is easier. (at least a single line string)

Answer (score 0):

I would use two regular expressions for this:

1. `/(\/\*.*?\/)|(#.+?$)/m` to find all the comments, the "m" modifier is to enable multiline
2. `/"[^"]*?"/` to find all the strings

If you apply the highlighting to the comments first and only after to the strings, the invalid comments should disappear.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to avoid ^^. I have currently a list of regex to load and strings and comments overriding each other. So if I apply a color for the comments first and then another color for the strings, they would be also colored in comments

Comment: You're right, didn't think of that :) Not sure if you can do without a parser though.

Comment: Have you considered checking if each match contain any of the others and override them in that case?

Comment: I think would be too overwhelming. Lets say I have a large document and the code gets colorized after each single char the user type. I think if I don't get an answer I will simply display strings colored inside comments. (not the best solution, but faster than the mix of both)