# Create a function with PDO::prepare that has question marks in its create statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a function with a PDO connection :

```
$sql = "
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_procedure`;

    CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
        SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    BEGIN
      /* this goes wrong ? */
      SET @a = 1;

    END;
";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test123", "root", "password");

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

The problem is that this function has a question mark inside the comment.
Because of `prepare` , PDO now tries to bind a parameter to this question mark, which of course fails.

Since I cannot be sure that all my function create statements have no question marks inside comments, is there any way to get around this problem?

***UPDATE***

- using DELIMITER does not seem to work at all with PDO, so I updated the original question. Somehow using DELIMITER is not necessary here ?
- using PDO::exec() seems to work with question marks inside the comment, since no parameters are binded then

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work, and is no real solution, since it is for a cloning tool, for which I have no control over the function create statements.

Comment: If you are not using any bindings, you don't need to prepare the statement. Just call 'query' directly.

Comment: Tried 'ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES' but didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in your requirements you won't have control of what you will execute, maybe you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or even [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove the question mark inside comments.

Comment: No real solution as well, because inside the comment there can be sql-statements that contain a question mark, for example in a string. Re-enabling that code would result in a wrong statement then.

Comment: If you adapt this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204228/2237854) to SQL string character (single quotes) and comment caracter \\ (in regex \/\/) I believe this should work removing all comments from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`$db->prepare()` is only needed if you are sending parameters/variables to the query.

If you are not sending any parameters, then there is no need to *prepare* the query.  Just use

```
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: PDO::query() cannot contain multiple statements, only the DROP PROCEDURE is executed then.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you mention in your comments, use `exec` since it has no parameters to bind.

```
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

and no, you don't need `DELIMITER` with PDO or the trailing `;`